# Getting ValueError: Unable to parse string "20,00,00,000" . while trying to change the datatype to numeric. Is there any way to change the data type

Tags: python, pandas

```
df[['Amount in USD']] = df[['Amount in USD']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

ValueError: Unable to parse string "20,00,00,000" at position 0

Comment: how is 20,00,00,000 a numeric value?

Comment: @XxJames07-  -- That's how commas are done in India,  Just like 200,000,000 in the west.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the commas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [ "20,00,00,000" ],
    [ "1,00,00,000" ]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['USD'])

df['USD'] = df['USD'].str.replace(',','').apply(pd.to_numeric)
```